# Arranging multiple canvas horizontally with bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, html5-canvas

I am trying to make three canvas inline horizontally but I am unable to do so. I also want to see two canvas in one line once the size of window is reduced to small/xs. My code is as following.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6">
          <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
          <canvas id="myCanvasa" width="300" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
          <canvas id="myCanvasb" width="300" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Current output is like this

[image: Current result]

**Desired result**
[image: Desired Result]

Comment: use display flex, inline block in css file

Comment: Thanks Ashish, I tried another solution which is as following. It worked for me :)

Comment: Its looks perfect, mine was just starter, keep going buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arranging each element in a seperate div and using `sm` instead of `xs` has helped me to attain the desired result.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <canvas id="myCanvasa" width="300" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <canvas id="myCanvasb" width="300" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```